# Trying to register voice with javax.sound

Tags: java, audio

I am willing to register some audio from my microphone using javax.sound API, but the generated file cannot be read by my audio players.

I wrote a test method that starts a thread to register, waits some seconds, notify to interrupt registration, waits some more seconds and then persists the recorded audio to disk.

Here's the code (excluding exception management).

```
public void record() {
        VoiceRecorder voiceRecorder = new VoiceRecorder();
        Future<ByteArrayOutputStream> result = executor.submit(voiceRecorder);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        voiceRecorder.signalStopRecording();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        ByteArrayOutputStream audio = result.get();

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("./" + filename + ".mp3");
        stream.write(audio.toByteArray());
        stream.close();
}
```

VoiceRecorder is a class of mine, whose core code is this:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream call() {
AudioFormat standardFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 128, 16, 1, 2, 128, false);
TargetDataLine microphone = null;
microphone = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);    
microphone.open(format);

int numBytesRead;
byte[] data = new byte[microphone.getBufferSize() / 5];

// Begin audio capture.
microphone.start();

ByteArrayOutputStream recordedAudioRawData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

while (!stopped) {
    // Read the next chunk of data from the TargetDataLine.
    numBytesRead = microphone.read(data, 0, data.length);
    // Save this chunk of data.
    recordedAudioRawData.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
}

return recordedAudioRawData;
}
```

This code is run by my executor and registration happens, in fact a non-empty file is generated (684 bytes for 3 seconds, 988 bytes for 4 seconds), but it does not get opened with my players (e.g. VLC).

Where should I look for the issue? Is there any alternative to this approach you would recommend? Next step will be to reproduce the recorded audio. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are just writing the raw PCM bytes you have read to the file, this is not a format that most players will know how to deal with. You need to use something like `AudioSystem.write` to write the file in a recognized format.

Comment: Probably that was my issue. It was enough to change the AudioFormat to new AudioFormat(16000, 8, 2, true, true) and saving the file as Wav: AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, audioFile);

Comment: @greg-449  would you please move your comment to answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are just writing the raw PCM bytes you have read to the file, this is not a format that most players will know how to deal with.

You need to use something like `AudioSystem.write` to write the file in a recognized format.